# WsHttpBinding on .Net Core

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-core, soap, wshttpbinding

I'm migrating a `.Net 4.x` project to `.Net Core 3.1`. This project is heavily dependent on `SOAP` web services. As `.Net Core` does not support configuration based WCF service consumption, I call the service by code. Current project uses `ws2007HttpBinding` binding.

My problem is that `ws2007HttpBinding` does not exists officially in `.Net Core`. I have no option other than `HttpBinding`, `HttpsBinding` and `CustomBinding`. I have tried all of them with different configurations, but each time encounter an error. Sometime it complaint about `https` scheme (service which I am using is `https`), sometimes it says it has expected `text/xml` but has not seen it, and it maybe a result of different SOAP protocls each side is using, and sometimes I just get timeout error.

In my last try, I installed [Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 3.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/) and [System.ServiceModel.Http 4.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Http/) and later 4.8.0-preview3.20412.3. The latter has implenetations of both [`WsHttpBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and [`Ws2007HttpBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.ws2007httpbinding?view=netframework-4.8). But, neither worked. This time I got error:

System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

Any solution or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Here it is the stack trace and parts of the code:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Specified method is not supported.)
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at System.ServiceModel.MessageSecurityOverHttp.CreateSecurityBindingElement(Boolean isSecureTransportMode, Boolean isReliableSession, MessageSecurityVersion version)
   at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpSecurity.CreateMessageSecurity(Boolean isReliableSessionEnabled, MessageSecurityVersion version)
   at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding.CreateMessageSecurity()
   at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBindingBase.CreateBindingElements()
   at System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding.CreateBindingElements()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.EnsureInvariants(String contractName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint.EnsureInvariants()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.System.ServiceModel.IAsyncCommunicationObject.OpenAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OpenAsyncInternal(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletion(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.EnsureOpened()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannel()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelInternal()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.get_Channel()
   at client.Inquiry_DataAsync(String NationalCode) in C:\Users\Reference.cs:line 5577
   at class1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<Inquiry_Data>b__0() in C:\Users\Code.cs:line 349
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification
```

code:

```
        PermissiveCertificatePolicy.Enact("*");

        var binding = new WSHttpBinding();

        binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(
            binding, new EndpointAddress("https://example.com/service.svc"));
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
        client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication
        {
            CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
            RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
        };

        _result = Task.Run(() => client.InquiryDataAsync("ABC")).Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Core does not support Wshttpbinding, wcf only supports BasicHttpBinding, CustomBinding, NetHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding：

[image]

So there are two current solutions:

**Modify the binding of the server, do not use Wshttpbinding.**

**The client continues to use the .net framework.**

For more information about WCF Features in core, you can refer to this link:

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.1.0.md

Comment: I can't modify server binding, we have not control on it. Moreever, `System.ServiceModel.Http` has a limited support of `WsHttpBinding`. Unfortunately, this support is not enough in my case.

Comment: In this case, the client can only use the .net framework.